# What is <image> tag, and how is it different from <img> tag

Tags: html, image

I have the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<body>
<?php
$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','alsk1029','karan');
$query="select * from project where image_id>16";
$data=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{

echo '<br /><image src="'.'images/'.$row['image'].'" /><br /><br /><a href="script.php?    name='.'images/'.$row['image'].'">Downlaod</a>';
echo '<br /><br /><a href="remove.php?name='.'images/'.$row['image'].'">Remove</a>';
}
?>
```

even after @unlink, there is no pic in my images folder, but it still keeps on showing me the image, though when i download the image, it shows an empty file being downloaded, if i use `<image>` tag instead of the `<img>`. On using `<img>` it doesnt display the image? what really is  tag?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just a mistake?

Comment: it's showing me the results! i cant say any more!

Comment: is there any <image> tag anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some browsers may support some weird tags invented by the browser developers on their own. For instance, MS IE may support some tags generated by their FrontPage or even by Word. However, I'd recommend not to rely on them and to follow W3C standards to provide cross-browser compatibility.